# What does a "non viable function" error mean?

Tags: c++, unreal-5, websocket

I am trying to use a websocket and some C++ code in order to trigger a function `toogleLight` every time Unreal connects with a server.

But I have the following error: "No viable function." in this line of code:

```
WebSocket->OnConnected().AddUObject(this, &UWebSocketTestGameInstance::OnClientConnected);
```

How can I solve this?

Here is the code:

```c
// WebSocketTestGameInstance.cpp


#include "WebSocketTestGameInstance.h"

#include "MySimplelight.h"
#include "WebSocketsModule.h"

void UWebSocketTestGameInstance::Init()
{
    
    Super::Init();


    if (!FModuleManager::Get().IsModuleLoaded("WebSockets"))
    {

        FModuleManager::Get().LoadModule("WebSockets");
    }

    WebSocket = FWebSocketsModule::Get().CreateWebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

    
    WebSocket->Connect();

    WebSocket->OnConnected().AddUObject(this, &UWebSocketTestGameInstance::OnClientConnected);
}

void UWebSocketTestGameInstance::Shutdown()
{

    if(WebSocket->IsConnected())
    {
        WebSocket->Close();
    }
    Super::Shutdown();
}

void UWebSocketTestGameInstance::OnClientConnected()
{
    // Get a reference to the MySimpleLight actor instance
    AMySimplelight* MyLight = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AMySimplelight>(); // Or find an existing instance

    if (MyLight)
    {
        MyLight->ToogleLight();
    }
}
```

```c
//WebSocketTestGameInstance.h

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Engine/GameInstance.h"
#include "IWebSocket.h"

#include "WebSocketTestGameInstance.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class WEBSOCKETTEST_API UWebSocketTestGameInstance : public UGameInstance
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:

    virtual void Init() override;
    virtual void Shutdown() override;
    
    TSharedPtr<IWebSocket> WebSocket;

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnClientConnected();
    
};
```